# Set default values of generic

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

Quick question, I have a Generic class that I'm instantiating, but I'm having problem with primitives that are setted by default in the class.

```
public class HeroLaunchData
{
    public int player;
    public int team;
    //....
    public bool withAnimation = true;
    //....
```

When I do the new of the generic this is not asigned, any idea why this may be?

Btw, I'm doing the new like

```
public static T WoRDeserializer<T>(string serializedObj, char separator = ';') where T : class, new()
{
    //...
    T obj = new T();
    //...
```

Thanks!

Comment: probably default(T) if I understood your question. Also don't post pictures

Comment: Not reproduced here. Can you post the code you have as text?

Comment: @mybirthname That will always yield `null`.

Comment: Yes probably I don't understand him correclty, is he asking of default values of player and team ?

Comment: `When I do the new of the generic this is not assigned` **What** is not assigned?

Comment: withAnimation should be true. maybe you change those default value in parameterless contructor which you didn't show us?

Comment: Quick answers are only possible for well-written answers. Code snippets that actually reproduce a problem result in the quickest answers

Answer (score 1):

For setting *default* value for any *Generic class/method* you must use `default` keyword.

[default Keyword in Generic Code (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.140).aspx)

> In generic classes and methods, one issue that arises is how to assign
>   a default value to a parameterized type T when you do not know the
>   following in advance:
>
> - Whether T will be a reference type or a value type.
> - If T is a value type, whether it will be a numeric value or a struct.
>
> Given a variable t of a parameterized type T, the statement t = null
>   is only valid if T is a reference type and t = 0 will only work for
>   numeric value types but not for structs. The solution is to use the
>   default keyword, which will return null for reference types and zero
>   for numeric value types. For structs, it will return each member of
>   the struct initialized to zero or null depending on whether they are
>   value or reference types. For nullable value types, default returns a
>   System.Nullable, which is initialized like any struct.

Instead of initializing new instance of `T` use `default(T) in your code.

```
public static T WoRDeserializer<T>(string serializedObj, char separator = ';') where T : class, new()
{
    //...
    // T obj = new T();
    T obj = default(T);
    //...
```